# How to get django-all auth to pass data to custom user model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I'm making a site in Django using django-allauth for authentication.

I've created a custom user class in account.models to add a custom field, UserExtraFiledSignup , i have added image field so user can upload profile photo for his account during signup but i got issue

The issue I have is that the when user create account and upload photo Actually it's don't uploaded i don't know what is the error

> Edit

my app | models.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(default='', upload_to='images/')

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

my app | forms.py :

```
class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['profile_img'] = forms.FileField(required = False)

    def save(self, request):
        user = super(CustomSignupForm, self).save(request)
        user.profile_img = self.cleaned_data.get('profile_img')
        user.save()
        return user
```

my app | settings.py :

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'signup': 'blog_app.forms.CustomSignupForm',
}
```

error when i hit migrate

`ERRORS: auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'. HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'User.groups'. auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User. user_permissions'. HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'. blog_app.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'. HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'User.groups'. blog_app.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'U ser.user_permissions'. HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.`

what is the error please how to fix it ?

Comment: Did you include enctype='multipart/form-data' in the formtag? It also looks like you are saving the photo in the user object and not in the UserExtraSignup object.

Comment: yes i did , but what are you mean about `It also looks like you are saving the photo in the user object and not in the UserExtraSignup object`

Comment: Profile_photo is in model UserExtraFiledSignup and not User. You try to save it into the user object: user.Profile_photo

Comment: @hendrikschneider i tried Yousuf M.N awnser but i got error

Comment: Did you try the solution I mentioned below for the new error?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to create a model for a single field?

You can just add it to your `User` model directly:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(default='', upload_to='images/')

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

You also don't need to override the account adapter. All you need is a good `CustomSignupForm`:

```
class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['profile_img'] = forms.FileField(required = False)

    def save(self, request):
        user = super(CustomSignupForm, self).save(request)
        user.profile_img = self.cleaned_data.get('profile_img')
        user.save()
        return user
```

That should do the trick for you.

Comment: thanks but i do that but i want ask where i should add your code , in models.py  at my app or in allauth.account.models.py ?

Comment: i add models code to my app  model then i edit forms then i hit python manage.py migrate but i got this error * i will edit q for view new error

Comment: You should never change anything in any third-party apps, instead you override them.

Comment: For the error: go to 'settings.py' in your project and add "AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'appname.modelname' ". this should take care of the error